# How to calculate the number of instructions that a microcontroller can execute before a specified event

Tags: synchronous, spi, pic32

I am trying to understand this exercise about PIC32 microcontroller.

I have a SPI peripheral module which can operate with a peripheral clock as fast as 50 MHz and it is connected to Serial EEPROMs which operates with a maximum clock rate of 5 MHz.

The SPI port is configured with a baud rate generator at 4.5 MHz in order to be compatible with the memory device.

The exercise says that with this configuration, the PIC32 is capable to execute at least 140 instructions before each new byte of data is received.

Unfortunately, neither the clock system nor the number of clock's tick for instruction are specified.

So, I assumed that the system's clock frequency is 72 MHz (from datasheet) and only one clock's tick for instruction as first approximation.

Can anyone suggest the correct method in order to calculate the number of instructions expected before one data byte is received?

Thanks in advance.